# Aggregation framework performance on a 10M collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of 10M documents, that is a pre-aggregation of daily events.

A simple `$group` took more than 8s, is this performance normal ?

Some date from the profiler :

```
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "analytics.$cmd",
    "command" : {
        "aggregate" : "aggregation",
        "pipeline" : [
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : "",
                    "hits" : {
                        "$sum" : "$hits"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 15,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(17169805),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(8582619),
            "w" : NumberLong(294)
        }
    },
    "responseLength" : 78,
    "millis" : 8594,
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-12-04T15:57:38.217Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

Here is one single document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("529e21ee67e807418500daeb"),
    "date" : ISODate("2012-09-19T00:00:00Z"),
    "hits" : 1,
    "infos" : {
        "sourceValue" : NumberLong(1),
        "eventType" : "createUser",
        "sourceType" : "user",
        "instance" : "xxx",
        "targetType" : "user",
        "targetValue" : NumberLong(15)
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL: "A simple group" on 10M docs. Try doing this on a SQL db. 8 sec is fast....

Comment: I must agree you are summing up all 10m records by the looks of it there and then saying that you are getting bad performance, bad performance compared to what exactly?

Comment: I compare to summing 10M integers on my laptop (200ms) @Sammaye

Comment: Summing them up where? In a normal program, I would understand that, you using an entire database here

Comment: I compare summing up 10M integers in a little test program and summing up 10M documents (a whole collection) on a given field in MongoDB. In both case data is in memory, so execution time should be similar. Am I wrong ?

Comment: If the data for the other test is held within the programs memory then no, program memory will always be faster to access then the TCP/IP protocol of the MongoDB server and then the indexes and then the data in RAM (if it really is in RAM that is).

Comment: Or are both test programs using MongoDB?

Comment: 1. sum up 10M integers in a standalone program 2. an aggregation on 10M doc. In both case, no TCP/IP.

Comment: There is TCP/IP if you are connecting to MongoDB, even on localhost

Comment: I agree. Nevertheless, mongo client connect to server, execute a query that took 8s, and sent back data to client. TCP/IP is clearly not the bottleneck.